# Javascript - Pop-up new parent window

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
function checkAlerts() {
    secondsSinceLoad += 1;
    for(var mj = 0 ; mj <= alertList.length; mj++) {
                    if(alertList[mj]['time'] < secondsSinceLoad && alertList[mj]['time'] > -1 ) {
                            alertmsg = alertList[mj]['type'] + ":" + alertList[mj]['name'] + "\n" +alertList[mj]['subtitle']+ "\n"+ alertList[mj]['description'] + "\n\n";
                            window.open(alertList[mj]['redirect'],"name1","width=800,height=500,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,copyhistory=no");
                    }
    }
    alertsTimeoutId = setTimeout("checkAlerts()",1000);
```

}

This is a scheduled popup. It creates a pop-up correctly, however if there are more than 1 scheduled pop-up **at same time** then only 1 pop-up is shown.

P.S. I'm presuming it's because the "parent popup has same window opened"

Help is appreciated.

Thanx.

Comment: cannot handle multiple pop-ups at once....

Answer (score 1):

Browsers ban the opening of multiple popups in a loop to stop malicious sites bombing users with lots of new windows.

Work around it by avoiding popups and displaying all your content in a single window.